# Trying to populate select based on previous 2 selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Can You Please Find Out The Problem In The Following Code 
I am trying to populate 1 select option based on previous 2 select options.
For example, you will select option 1 and then select option 2 based on those 2 options I will get 3rd option.
Here is my jquery part

```
/*This Is Basically My Jquery Part Which will Take 2 values from selects*/
$(".asset").change(function(){

    var id=$(this).val();
    console.log(id);
    var dataString1 = 'id='+ encodeURIComponent(id);
    console.log(dataString1);

    $(".amc").change(function(){

        var aid=$(this).val();
        console.log(aid);
        var dataString2 = 'aid='+ encodeURIComponent(aid);
        console.log(dataString2);

        //console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch.php",
            data : {dataString1: id,dataString2: aid},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".scheme").html(html);
            } 
        });

    });

});
```

Here is the fetch part

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');


if($_POST['id'] && $_POST['aid'])
{

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $aid=$_POST['aid'];



    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Master_MutualFundMasters WHERE AssetClassID=:id AND AMCID = :aid");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $stmt->execute(array(':aid' => $aid));


    ?><option selected="selected">Select City :</option>
    <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['WW_UniqueInvestmentCode']; ?>"><?php echo $row['PrimarySchemeName']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

When I check my console it is showing me the data but its not passing on next page

Comment: I have reformatted your script code, hope you can see better what you have done in there. For example, on each `.asset` change you add another change event to `.amc`. I guess that was not the logic at first place.

Comment: then can you please help me with the logic

Comment: @skobaljic yes sir how can i get the 2 select option value on change event at the same time , i am also not geting with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
since you are asking 
In your console it is showing me the data but its not passing on next page means (fetch.php).
then you can do-

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch.php",
            data : {"id":dataString1,"aid":dataString2},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".scheme").html(html);
            } 
        });

and in fetch.php page.
if($_POST["id"] && $_POST["aid"])
{

    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $aid=$_POST["aid"];

    //write ur code here...
}   

I Hope this help u.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use select at beginning.
Example:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is select one option and then select second option my console is passing those ids